A circle is inscribed in a triangle, with three other circles in the corner regions. The radii are integers. Possible values of the largest radius?
Originally posted at MSE.

A circle with integer radius $R$ is inscribed in a triangle. Three other circles with integer radii $a,b,c$ are each tangent to the large circle and two sides of the triangle.


What are the possible values of $R$?

(As an analogy, here is a similar question and its answer: What are the possible values of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with integer side lengths? Answer: numbers with a prime factor of the form $4k+1$.)

It turns out that $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$.
So we require $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ and $R>\max(a,b,c)$ for $R, a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z^+}$. [EDIT: As @GMfromMO mentioned in the comments, it is not immediately clear whether these are sufficient conditions for $R$.]
For example, $22$ is a possible value of $R$, because $22=\sqrt{2\cdot 8}+\sqrt{8\cdot 18}+\sqrt{2\cdot 18}$ and $22>\max(2,8,18)$.
At the MSE post, @Will Jagy found that the numbers below $100$ that cannot be $R$ values are
$$1,2,4,7,13,14,17,23,28,34,37,43,46,49,53,67,73,97,98$$
This seems like an almost random sequence of numbers. The OEIS does not have this sequence (but it has a conjectured sequence of numbers not of the form $ab+bc+ac$).
At the MSE post, @mathlove found a procedure for testing whether a number is a possible value of $R$, but it is computationally heavy. Is there an easier test?

I don't quite see from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3699411/ that the conditions on $R$ are not only necessary but also sufficient. At any rate, the point I want to make (which was surely also remarked at MSE) is that if $a$, $b$, $c$, $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ are positive integers, then in fact $a=ka_1^2$, $b=kb_1^2$, $c=kc_1^2$, where $k$, $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$ are positive integers (see next comment). Hence $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ is of the form $k(a_1b_1+b_1c_1+c_1a_1)$, and vice versa.

The claim I made on $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}$ follows from the following result that is easy to prove by induction. Theorem. Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $\neq 2$. Let $x_1,\dotsc, x_n$ be elements in an algebraic closure of $K$ such that each $x_i^2$ lies in $K$. If the sum $x_1+\dotsb+x_n$ lies in $K$, but all the subsums of this sum (including the full sum) are nonzero, then each $x_i$ lies in $K$. Corollary. Let $q_1\dotsc,q_n$ be positive rational numbers such that $\sqrt{q_1}+\dotsb+\sqrt{q_n}$ is rational. Then each $\sqrt{q_i}$ is rational.

@GHfromMO OK, but there's a triangle so we require $R>\max(a,b,c)$.

I agree that if $R$ is good, then $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}>\max(a,b,c)$ with $R,a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}{>0}$. What I don't see immediately is the converse. That is, if $R=\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ac}>\max(a,b,c)$ with $R,a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}{>0}$, then why is $R$ good? How do we know that there are no further conditions on $R$?

@GHfromMO Good question. I don't know. I will have to think about that.

My answer doesn't say the converse is true. What my answer proved is that $R$ is of the form $\sqrt{ab}+\sqrt{bc}+\sqrt{ca}$ where $a,b,c,R$ are positive integers such that $a\le b\le c\lt R$ if and only if $R$ is of the form $(AB+BC+CA)\color{red}{\times D}$ where $A,B,C,D$ are positive integers such that $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$. So, we want to know if a given number is of the form $(AB+BC+CA)\color{red}{\times 1}$ where $A,B,C$ are positive integers such that $A\le B\le C\lt\sqrt{AB+BC+CA}$, i.e. if a given number is good.
